# ホワッとした子 >>What does this mean about a girl?

Tags: meaning, expressions, japanese-to-english

when reading i came across this expression ,that describe a girl
**ホワッとした子 >>Please explain to me what does this mean thanks**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's used for someone that has soothing atmosphere, maybe "goofy" is closest expression?

I think people who are a little goofy, but have a charming or gentle kind of vibe tend to be called "ホワッとした子", or "天然".